# Kotlin extension properties do not work in Kotlin script

Tags: kotlin

```
var StringBuilder.lastChar: Char
    get() = get(length - 1)
    set(value: Char) {
        this.setCharAt(length - 1, value)
    }


val sb = StringBuilder("Kotlin?")
sb.lastChar = '!'
println(sb)
```

When I run this code with `kotlinc -script`, the compiler throws:

```
extensions.kts:3:14: error: unexpected type specification
    set(value: Char) {
```

However, this code works without problems when compiled. 
So, does it mean extension properties cannot work in kotlin script mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kotlin scripts just wrap code in main function. And extension properties doesn't work when defined inside functions. I think this is bug, and you can submit it here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT.